# coordinate layout issue while loading in frameLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-coordinatorlayout

I am working on code that have `FrameLayout` and customview at bottom. I loaded a fragment inside FrameLayout, which is having `CoordinatorLayout` with `ViewPager` inside.

So problem is `ViewPager` takes full height of the phone and hide contents of list behind customview. Here is Code:

main_layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/root_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/playerView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/playerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/player_size"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#D7D7D7"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Player View"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment_view.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs_view_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/tabs_view_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

In above image you can see some content of list is hidden beside PlayerView.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `LinearLayout` with `layout_weight` instead of `RelativeLayout` `inside main_layout.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/root_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/playerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/player_size"
        android:background="#D7D7D7"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Player View"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i just tried your code ...not working for me, still that content is hidden as in above image... :|

Comment: Try to remove this    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" properties and let me know.